# syntax error while applying tapply to a vector

Tags: r, list, data-structures, tapply

I was practicing the lectures of coursers on R programming, in one of the lectures where he demonstrates tapply() function I just copy pasted what is taught in the lectures but got a syntax error

```
x <- c(norm(10),runif(10), rnorm(10,1))
f <- g1(3,10)
tapply(x, f, mean)
```

Results should look like this

```
tapply(x, f, mean)
1 2 3
0.1144464 0.5163468 1.2463678
```

But what I am getting is an error value

```
x <- c(norm(10),runif(10), rnorm(10,1))
Error in norm(10) : 'A' must be a numeric matrix
f <- g1(3,10)
Error: could not find function "g1"
tapply(x, f, mean)
Error in tapply(x, f, mean) : object 'f' not found
```

Comment: You have not shown us what `g1` is, although I suspect what you really wanted was the R function `gl`. Lowercase-l is not same as numeral-1.  You have probably also left out an "r" in "rnorm". Voting to close as related to typos. (And removing all the extraneous tags.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have some typos in your code:

```
x <- c(rnorm(10),runif(10), rnorm(10,1))
f <- gl(3,10)
tapply(x,f,mean)
```

This will give you the output you want.

Your typos are:

`g1` should be `gl`

and

`norm` should be `rnorm`

**update**

No problem. It might be helpful to learn about `apropos` in R. It's sort of like a search function for functions/objects. [Documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/apropos.html)

If you can't remember the name of a function (let's say `rnorm`) but you can remember the beginning of it (`rnor`), you can type

`apropos("rnor")`

which will return

`[1] "rnorm"`

Then you can type `?rnorm` to access the documentation for rnorm.

Comment: No problem. I updated my answer with some additional information that will hopefully help you.